# Removing obsolete data with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have IoT devices that read pressure data into MongoDB via MQTT.

The thing is, it takes a lot of resources to graph this data over time, also it's a waste of storage space. I, therefore, want to make it so that the saved data gets gradually removed. I want to keep 1/1 for an hour, 1/4 for a day, 1/4 of that again for a week, and 1/4 of that perpetually. My original idea was to use some sort of modulo when posting the data, setting the correct time limits.

I've tried looking at the MongoDB TTL function, but it seems to me that it's setting a timer for the entire collection, and the only option I have is which particular documents will be affected by it.

I have Java middleware posting the data to MongoDB for me, is it better to make a java program doing these things? I'm still not sure how I can delete every *n* entries.

Comment: You should probably remove the `aggregation-framework` tag as it's not on that subject, it might influence searches wrongly.

Comment: @Plancke I think that the aggregation framework might be a good way to create buckets of document ids which would belong together, l where then more and more ids get dropped over time

Comment: @DanielF Fair enough, I guess they could use the $sample stage to select random documents from a specific timeframe.

Comment: @Plancke well I forgot to mention it in my question, but I did think about using $match to find stuff. Then I had trouble using objects in that function, such as new Date(Date.now()), and kinda gave it up. But I'm looking for ideas using the aggregate framework also.

Answer (score 1):

Yea at my firm, I've had to clean up obsolete data as well.  Luckily the collection's documents had an obsolete date (basically a "last modified date") and I was able to use Java to cull the collection of documents that passed a threshold.

I would probably write a component or script that's triggered to run daily that will look at an element in your documents (date, hopefully) and then start removing every fourth element or what not based on the array of objects returned that are X amount of time old.

Comment: That's my initial idea, but I was hoping to use the TTL function somehow in order to save me the trouble of this. With the script method I get more control, but it also adds more components. Glad we are thinking the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The mongo TTL Indexes are per document. See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/

You need a field with a Date value. In your case, I'd suggest setting this field to the date you want to expire the document at and then creating an index like this:

`db.collection.createIndex( { "expireAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0} )`

This will make mongo expire the document when that date has been reached.

Keep in mind that as you mentioned, you'll need to determine the expiry date beforehand, so you'll need to do your 1/4ths stuff when inserting the document.

Comment: Hey thanks for that info. I don't have very important historical data right now, so I can work on what's ahead. So what you're saying is, I gotta make an additional data field in each document containing the time, and then using that data in conjunction with the createIndex method. The big con is obviously that it will make my data take up 25% more space..

Comment: Yeah, it'll use space for the field and the index, the benefit is though that you don't need a job running every x hours to clean up, mongo handles it all internally. 

It sort of depends on the data you have, if your document already has on ObjectId you can use that to determine the insert timestamp as well, in which case using a cleanup job won't increase storage at all.